# Typescript with polymer-cli based project

Tags: javascript, typescript, polymer

How can I use typescript with a polymer-cli based project ? I use polymer-cli to build an application and I have some helper codes written in typescript.

Comment: Does polymer-cli generate ES6?

Answer (score -1):

You might also want to try https://flowtype.org/. The other answer here mentions https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/blog/es6 where the author recommends using Babel.

If you follow their instructions or visit http://babeljs.io/docs/setup/ and get Babel set up, you can easily integrate Flow by installing `flow-bin` with npm into your project and installing/adding `babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types` to your Babel config.

Babel has great integration with many tools. We spent a long time making sure of that, so many use it that there's likely instructions floating around for any tool you want to use, and since Flow hooks into that it is not much more to add.

Let me know if you have any questions, I'm on both the Babel and Flow teams so I can help out a lot!